# PHP won't str_replace single quotes from database

Tags: php, mysql, ascii, content-type

This is really weird to explain, so here it goes...

I'm fetching data from phpmyadmin that contains unescaped single quotes. I'm trying to convert `'` to `&apos;` by using `Content-Type: text/html;` in a php header.

In one column of the database, this is the value: `This year's...`

I set the content type to `<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); ?>`

I fetched the data with `mysql_fetch_assoc()`, so it should output, `This year&apos;s`. But, it outputs `This year�s...`.

I then manually deleted `This year's...` from the database and replaced it with the same `This year's...` (directly in the database). I set the content type to `text/html` again and got this:

```
This year&apos;s...
```

That's it... this is almost imossible to explain. A single quote is submitted to the database through a form. I fetch it and set the content type to text/html and it outputs `'` as `�`. If I go into the database, manually delete the `'`, and replace it with the same `'`, it then outputs `&apos;`.

Has anyone ever experienced this weird quirk or recognize what it might be?

UPDATE:

The value in the database is `This year's` which was uploaded by a form. The quote is unescaped in the database. Here's how I'm fetching the data. I want the `'` to be converted to `&apos;`.

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    include('init.inc.php');

    function get_feeds() {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
        while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

            $text = $fetch['text'];         

            echo $text;         

            }
        }

?>
<?php get_feeds(); ?>
```

It outputs `This year�s`.

I then delete `This year's` from the database and manually write `This year's` in it's place. It outputs this `This year&apos;s`.

Comment: It would be better to share code too

Comment: I added a bit of code. The code is pretty self explanatory. The single quotes in the DB are all unescaped and were uploaded by a form.

Comment: use `$text = html_entity_decode($fetch['text']);`

Comment: Are you really working with utf8 completely? Did you send a query like this after connect to your db: 'SET NAMES utf8'? Somtimes data is not stored as utf8 correctly.

Comment: Steven, it's set to UTF8. @Amir I tried that, but no change. I think I'm going to have to change how the data is inserted to the db. I'm just using mysql_real_escape_string, but will add addslashes.

Comment: how did you manually write? in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Directly in the db, I deleted and rewrote the text by hand. I literally deleted -This year's-, then rewrote -This year's- in the same field.

Comment: have you tried an htaccess like this: AddDefaultCharset UTF-8? If the string is stored correctly the sign should be shown without converting to &apos;. The fact that entity_decode not works is another hint that its not really an ' in your db

Comment: I put - AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 - in the .htaccess and it outputted - 
This year�s - Same thing. I guessing it's how the text is being inserted into the db.

Comment: yes insert a new entry with active .htaccess! Another way to find out is to do utf8_encode ( $text) before output. If you see the right things with your old data then its iso.

Comment: I'm very confused.  Firstly, `Content-Type: text/html` is set by default in PHP: one doesn't need to set it explicitly (although, by default, no character set is specified in the header but this can be changed with the [`default_charset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) directive).  Secondly, specifying such a header (whether explicitly or implicitly) *does not* automatically encode HTML entities: one must explicitly call [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).  Are you *sure* that you're getting encoded output of `&apos;`?

Comment: Thirdly, make sure that you are following all of the advice in [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/a/279279).  Fourthly, your title mentions `str_replace()`, which doesn't appear to have anything to do with the question?

Answer (score 0):

before inserting in to database Convert special characters to HTML entities

```
htmlspecialchars("This year's");
```